Place to discuss in-depth cryptoanalysis
Many heads are better then one, right? 
Is there a place where we can discuss the analysis of certain cryptographic schemes in detail? In particular, I'm actually writing a cryptoanalysis of https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06862, but in my humble opinion this should be public and open for discussion.
I'm not a fan of writing a paper on that topic, and then putting it on the arXiv or wherever, because that is too slow and it's better to discuss these things "on the fly".
However, it's important to have certain standards; for example, on Reddit, whose discussions are spammed with a lot of noise from people who lack a proper background in mathematics.

This would seem to be an ideal place to ask cryptography questions. There's even a specific tag for the homomorphic encryption of your paper. You'll have realised that this forum works best for specific targeted questions. Just ask some and see how the cards fall...

You're free to talk about cryptanalysis and entire schemes in depth in The Side Channel, there is no rule against it there. 

You're not guaranteed an answer or valuable input, but that will likely be the case anywhere unless you are paying a professional.

